# Range of IF statements in C programming

Tags: c, if-statement, statements

```
if (5>=hour && hour<9){
    if(minute<7){
        printf("%d:00");
        return 0;}
    else if (8<=minute && minute<22){
        printf("%d:15",hour);
        return 0;}
    else if (22<=minute && minute<37){
        printf("%d:30",hour);
        return 0;}
    else if (38<=minute && minute<52){
        printf("%d:45",hour);
        return 0;}
    else{
        hour+=1;
        printf("%d:00");
        return 0;}
```

After compiling the value of the code is completely off, what is wrong with my statements?
I can make the code longer and make it work but I am trying to simplify it.

EDIT: Basically I am trying to say if I input "5:01" output should be "5:00" and if my input is "5:22" output should be "5:30".

However my output values comes out to be "2686748:00"

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Also, the first if statement conditional and first else statement conditional are unlike the second else conditional. Have you learned about integer division and truncation?

Comment: "after compiling the value of the code is completely off" -- sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: You are missing details. If minute is 7 or 37, the code is completely wrong.

Comment: Some of your `printf` calls look different from the others....

Comment: What is your intention here: `if (5>=hour && hour<9)`? Are you looking for a value `<9`, or a value `<=5`? Or perhaps `hour >= 5 && hour < 9`? It seems like you may want to rework that conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `printf("%d:00");` should be:

```
printf("%d:00", hour);
```

See if you can turn up your compiler warning level, modern compilers tend to be able to warn about this sort of mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I've just started programming and have been at it for so long that I can't even find my mistakes.

Comment: @Quan: We all have to start somewhere. I still make stupid mistakes all the time!